# Why is using VPN can increase my speedtest result?

Tags: networking, performance, vpn, broadband

My internet connection is 2 megabit download. I connect to my VPN and did speedtest and the download speed result goes up to 11+ megabit download. However when I try to download any file the speed just fluctuate around my original speed of 2 megabit.

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: my guess is you are seeing the speed between your test site and your vpn's exit node, but that's just a hunch.

Comment: The speed depends on the server sending the file and how large the file is.

Answer (score 3):

Its because of the compression offered by your VPN. Everything that passes through your VPN is being compressed and you are probably downloading a highly compressible file when doing your speedtest that is why it can go as high as 11+mb/s. In real life most files that we download (eg: mp3, avi, mkv) are already compressed that is why you wont notice the same speed up on your speedtest.